# MySQL server connection error?

Tags: java, mysql

My program is able to connect to `localhost` `MySQL server` to get the data from it. But when I uploaded the database onto a server I'm not able to connect any more.

```
final static String db_url = "jdbc:mysql://***.***.***.***:3306/oyutan";

String card = cardnumber.getText();
String pinn = pincode.getText();
String pindb = null;
String pinsql = "SELECT *  FROM `card` WHERE `card_number`=" + card + ";";
try {
    Class.forName(jdbc_driver);
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, "bilig", "199108");
    ps = con.prepareStatement(pinsql);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()); {
        pindb=rs.getString("code")+"";
        cardnumber.setText(" ");
        pincode.setText(" ");
    }
}
catch(Exception g) {
    System.out.println("Not Found!");
    g.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can access the database with Command line, but this gives me error "Host '***.***.***.***' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server". I gave myself all the privileges I need. Do I need another program such as `Tomcat`, `Apache`, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i gave myself all the privileges i need.

Apparently MySQL disagrees with you.

You GRANT permission to particular users on particular machines.  Here's an example:

```
create database contacts;
create user contacts identified by 'contacts';
-- this next one is what you're probably missing.
grant all on contacts.* to 'contacts'@'%';
grant select on `mysql`.`proc` to 'contacts'@'%';
use contacts;
```

Every use of the string "contacts" above is for an example of mine that happens to use a database with that name.  I created a user named 'contacts' with password 'contacts'.  (Not the most imaginative naming scheme.)

Adjust the values to meet you situation.

Comment: still same problem, not allowed.

Comment: Can you ping that remote server?  Can you access it using MySQL console?

Comment: actually when i enter grant all on contacts.* to 'contacts'@'%';
grant select on `mysql`.`proc` to 'contacts'@'%'; these, 0 rows afected. does this mean nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

is the database server local?
i mean is it localhost to your code?

if not, you need to add a Host to the username you are using, which is the IP your code will be running from, so the db-server allows this user to connect from remote machine.

Comment: no, its  a remote server. so i have to add my IP address on here ---con=DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, "bilig", "199108");--- instead of "bilig"

Comment: no its not in code, its a done on the db-server,below answer by duffymo is what you need

Comment: actually when i enter grant all on contacts.* to 'contacts'@'%'; grant select on mysql.proc to 'contacts'@'%'; these, 0 rows afected. does this mean nothing changed

Comment: you used contacts!! contacts should be replaced, with your DB name, and username, first contacts is db name, and 2nd contacts is the username